# Help identifying 8 pin connector

Tags: connector, identification

Where should I start when trying to identify this connector on a WaveShare epaper hat? I've browsed through more Mouser pages than I want to think about. The manufacturer (WaveShare) has been downright unhelpful.
Additionally, what crimp ends are appropriate for this type of connector?
[image]

I think I've narrowed this down to the following categories which still yields ~400 results:

- Connector > Header & Wire Housing
- 8 Position
- 1 Row
- Pitch ~2.5-2.54
- Female

What can I do to further narrow down this search?

Here are a few more pictures of the male and female parts of this connector. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:
As requested, here are images of the crimp-on ends for completeness
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please eject one pin on the cable-end of the connector and take a picture of the pin crimped to the wire.

Comment: upvote for the really good visual documentation

Comment: Not 2.5-2.54 mm though...

Comment: @jcaron How can you tell that it's not 2.5?

Comment: @DwayneReid do those images help? My macro camera is out of commission.

Comment: @AaronCiuffo Because that's what the spec sheet says, and because I can find a connector that looks like it in 2.0 but not in 2.5 or 2.54. I have a similar connector on another board (exactly the same, just 10 pins instead of 8) and it's clearly 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's a [JST PH 2.0](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199) connector.

[image]
[image]

Waveshare's product page for the [e-Paper HAT](https://www.waveshare.com/e-paper-driver-hat.htm) says the package includes a "PH2.0 20cm 8Pin x1" which then made things quite easy :-)

The connector is a JST PHR-8, available [here](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-8/455-1189-ND/608630) or [here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/8201488/?grossPrice=Y) for instance.

Comment: Thank you! This looks correct, but I just want to verify the end before I buy yet another **wrong** connector. I'm feeling *really* dense; for the life of me, I can't find a mention of the PH2.0 on the link above.

Comment: On the linked page, go to the "Package content" tab at the bottom. It states "PH2.0 20cm 8Pin x1" and even has a picture of the cable. To be sure it's 2.0, measure from the first to the last pin (you should find precisely 14 mm), and divide by 7.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, this is a [JST connector](https://hackaday.com/2017/12/27/jst-is-not-a-connector/), but there are quite some different ones (you'll have to measure relevant dimensions to find the specific one).
If it's not a JST, Molex has some similar connectors.

Searching the web is in deed not easy. When I look for a specific connector I usually go to my favorite distributer's website. I find criteria like "number of contacts" and "pitch" not helpful, instead I'd select "wire-to-board connectors" and go through product families/series. Of course you can odd out all connectors with a pitch that is obviously not right.

Comment: Because there are so many similar connectors, it's important to see one of the pins crimped to the wire.  That will help narrow down the possibilities.